# I like to return the json format from neo4j list in scala

Tags: json, scala, jdbc, neo4j, driver

I have a list with collection but when it returns the result it outputs something like this in my application:

```
[Record<{post: node<166>, comments: [node<168>, node<168>, node<169>, node<169>], likes: [node<171>, node<172>, node<171>, node<172>], comment_count: 4, like_count: 4}>]
```

Here is the function:

```
def retrieveRecords() =  {
    val driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4jUrl, AuthTokens.basic(userName, userPassword))
    val session = driver.session

    val script = s"MATCH (me { email: 'carl@yahoo.com' })-[rels:FRIEND*1..3]-(myfriend) WHERE ALL (r IN rels WHERE r.status = 'active') WITH COLLECT(myfriend) AS collected_friends UNWIND collected_friends AS activity MATCH (p:Posts {memberID:activity.memberID}) WITH (p) AS e  OPTIONAL MATCH (g:Comments {postID:e.postID})  OPTIONAL MATCH (h:Likes {postID:e.postID})  return e AS post, COLLECT(g) AS comments, COLLECT(h) AS likes, count(g) as comment_count, count(h) as like_count"
    val result: StatementResult = session.run(script)


    val record_data = if (result.hasNext()) {
      val e = result.next()
      val data =  result.list()

      Some(data)
      } else {
      None
    }

    session.close()
    driver.close()
    record_data
}
```

But this is the result i want:

```
[{
    "post": "{"
        post_title ":"
        Hadoop Tutorial ","
        post_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        post_description ":"
        This tutorial is a very simple explanation on haoop ","
        postID ":2,"
        post_email ":"
        steve @yahoo.com ","
        memberID ":3}",
        "comments": "[]",
        "likes": "[]",
        "comment_count": 0,
        "like_count": 0
    },
    {
        "post": "{"
        post_title ":"
        The Bamboo Tree ","
        post_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 01 ","
        post_description ":"
        This is the wonder tree,
        one of African greatest blessings ","
        postID ":1,"
        post_email ":"
        james @yahoo.com ","
        memberID ":2}",
        "comments": "[{"
        comment_text ":"
        This is a fantastice post ","
        email_email ":"
        steve @yahoo.com ","
        comment_email ":"
        steve @yahoo.com ","
        commentID ":1,"
        comment_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        postID ":1,"
        memberID ":3},{"
        comment_text ":"
        This is a fantastice post ","
        email_email ":"
        steve @yahoo.com ","
        comment_email ":"
        steve @yahoo.com ","
        commentID ":1,"
        comment_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        postID ":1,"
        memberID ":3},{"
        comment_text ":"
        Well said ","
        email_email ":"
        carl @yahoo.com ","
        comment_email ":"
        carl @yahoo.com ","
        commentID ":2,"
        comment_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        postID ":1,"
        memberID ":1},{"
        comment_text ":"
        Well said ","
        email_email ":"
        carl @yahoo.com ","
        comment_email ":"
        carl @yahoo.com ","
        commentID ":2,"
        comment_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        postID ":1,"
        memberID ":1}]",
        "likes": "[{"
        likeID ":1,"
        postID ":1,"
        like_email ":"
        steve @yahoo.com ","
        like_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        memberID ":3},{"
        likeID ":2,"
        postID ":1,"
        like_email ":"
        joe @yahoo.com ","
        like_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        memberID ":4},{"
        likeID ":1,"
        postID ":1,"
        like_email ":"
        steve @yahoo.com ","
        like_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        memberID ":3},{"
        likeID ":2,"
        postID ":1,"
        like_email ":"
        joe @yahoo.com ","
        like_date ":"
        2017 - 09 - 03 ","
        memberID ":4}]",
        "comment_count": 4,
        "like_count": 4
    }
]
```